# How to print the deleted file names along with path in shell script

Tags: shell

I am deleting the files in all the directories and subdirectories using the command below:

```
find . -type f -name "*.txt" -exec rm -f {} \;
```

But I want to know which are the files deleted along with their paths.  How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply add a `-print` argument to your `find`.

```
$ find . -type f -name "*.txt" -print -exec rm -f {} \;
```

As noted by @JonathanRoss below, you can achieve an equivalent result with the `-v` option to `rm`.

It's not the scope of your question, but more generally it gets more interesting if you want to delete directories recursively.  Then:

- a simple `-exec rm -r` argument keeps it silent
- a `-print -exec rm -r` argument reports the toplevel directories you're operating on
- a `-exec rm -rv` argument reports *all* you're removing

Comment: In case if i have deleted a folder using  the command rm -rf  **/generic  how to print  the path of the folder deleted

Comment: @JonathanRoss I considered it as well initially, but considered the `find` way more idiomatic. But it's a valid enough alternative I'm considering editing it in to show the various nuances.